# Database normalization. Which is better, inserting in one row or multiple row?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-normalization

I'm currently designing my tables. i have three types of user which is, **pyd**, **ppp** and **ppk**.  Which is better? inserting data in one row or in multiple row? 
which is better?

[image]

or
[image]

or any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would go for 3 tables:

**user_type**

typeID | typeDescription

**Main_table**

id_main_table | id_user | id_type

**table_bhg_i**

id_bhg_i | id_main_table | data1 | data2 | data3

Answer (score 1):

Although I see you are inserting IDs for each user , I don't quite understand how are  are you going to differentiate between the users , had I designed this DB ,  I would have gone for tables like

> tableName: UserTypes

this table would contain two field first would be ID and second would be type of user
like

> UsertypeID | UserType

the UsertypeID is a primary key and can be auto increment , while UserType would be your users **pyd** ,**ppk** or so on . Designing in this way would give you flexibility of adding data later on in the table without changing the schema of the table ,
the next you can edit a table for generating multiple users of a particular type, this table would refer the userID of the previous table , this will help you adding new user easily and would remove redundancy

> tableName:Users

this table would again contain two fields, the first field would be the id call and the secind field would be the usertypeId try

> UserId |UserName | UserTypeID

the next thing you can do is make a table to insert the data , let the table be called DataTable

> tableName: DataTable

this table will contain the data of the users and this will reference then easily

> DataTabID | DataFields(can be any in number) | UserID(refrences Users table)

these tables would be more than sufficient .If doubts as me in chatbox

Comment: are there multiple users in the same type ? for example for pyd user are there multiple users ?

Comment: yeah the in the above in the second table you can add as many as much users for each usertype , and the above is the most normalized form I could think of

Comment: no problem , you can ask any further problems too :)